# null is not an object(evaluting 'RNI18n.languages')

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm working on expo react native. when I'm running the app I'm getting error. I have installed the npm install react-native-i18n --save and even link it manually react-native link react-native-i18n. In my package.json  "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",. Any help will be appreciated.

I have imported like this import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';

Comment: Checkout the github page of the respective package most of the time,some would have already asked the question there.

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/xcarpentier/ex-react-native-i18n/blob/master/README.md

Comment: i checked but nothing is working.